How to fix crack in caulk?

I have no idea what I'm doing. New here, please Be kind thank you

fix what? ... what's in the picture?

Hi welcome! Is that window loose? If you hold the frame and wiggle it can you see the window moving relative to that crack you photographed?

Do you want to fix the crack below the trim, or the line at the top of the window, or....?

A wider shot of the area might allow better answers If people could see what might have contributed to this crack.

When the trim was installed the seam between the trim and window frame was caulked.  That caulk has split. It appears that the trim or the window frame has moved enough to cause that split.
The simple repair is to remove any loose caulk and apply new paintable latex caulk.  Paint to match the color when dry.
The bigger question is why the crack opened up?  This is why you need to check the window frame and the trim to see if anything is loose. The trim may need to be anchored with a few more nails or other repairs may be needed.  What exact repairs are is unknow until you do your examination.

I agree with RMDman, but I'll add that this is an odd place for caulk to begin with. I suspect it was added for one of these reasons:

To close a gap left by poor carpentry
To secure the trim where nailing may not have been ideal
To stop a draft

In all cases the caulk is either an unsatisfactory solution since it merely masks problems rather than solving them and doesn't perform well as an adhesive.
Therefore, I'd be cutting the caulk smoothly away, resecuring the trim by better means, and painting.
